# Query index in Cloudant doesn't return expected data

Tags: indexing, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I have a Cloudant DB on Bluemix with an index defined as:

```
{
 "index": {
  "fields": [
   { "typ": "asc" },
   { "sen": "asc" },
   { "tim": "asc" }
  ]
 },
 "type": "json"
}
```

WHen I have a query of the form

```
{
  "selector": {
    "tim": {"$gt": millisecs},
    "typ": "H"
  },
  "fields": ["sen","val","tim"],
  "sort": [
    { "typ": "asc" },
    { "sen": "asc" },
    { "tim": "asc" }
  ],
  "limit": readCount
}
```

it works perfectly. If I want to get everything, i.e. remove the condition `typ="H"`, I get the error

> "error":"no_usable_index","reason":"There is no index available for this selector."

I get the same response if I have `"typ" : { "$in": ["H", "T"] }`. I would have expected that the more generic query would work better than the one with extra selectors.

I just don't understand how this could be!

Comment: See comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35385834/query-index-in-cloudant-doesnt-return-expected-data/35398907?noredirect=1#comment59781819_35398907

Answer (score 0):

"typ" is the first field of your index, so is the basis of the ordering.

"tim", if it's the only element of the query, doesn't take advantage of the index, so it would trigger a full table scan if that query was allowed.

However you can ask explicitely for a full table scan if you add:

```
"_id": { "$gt": null }
```

See [the doc](https://docs.cloudant.com/cloudant_query.html#creating-selector-expressions), your case is not really described, but I think it's implied.

Comment: I tried this with the same results. I tried with the current index, and created another which included _id and both failed. I also tried with a text index and that's not working either although I still have a few permutations to try. The doc is really poor - it tries its best, but it's written from the point of view of someone who is thoroughly familiar with Cloudant so they can't see why it's poor.

Comment: I agree that the doc is lacking in some parts. For indexes, I think that the constraint is that you have to have the first field in the query to be able to use them. Strange that the `_id` index is not working.

Comment: @BrendanMurray did you try `"typ": { "$gt": "" }` ?

Comment: {
  "selector": {   
   "_id": { "$gt": null },
     "tim": {"$gt": 10}
  },
  "fields": ["sen","val","tim"],
 
  "limit": 1
}       This works but you cant have sort  here.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to create separate indexes for these fields and run the same query?

Comment: Yes, loads of different combinations and permutations. I haven't had time to look at this lately, but I think my next attempt will be via a view.

Comment: https://docs.cloudant.com/cloudant_query.html#creating-selector-expressions"    You can create more complex selector expressions by combining operators. However, for Cloudant Query indexes of type json, you cannot use ‘combination’ or ‘array logical’ operators such as $regex as the basis of a query. Only the equality operators such as $eq, $gt, $gte, $lt, and $lte (but not $ne) can be used as the basis of a more complex query".  This might be the reason why you are facing problems when using just "$in" in the selector.